# "Раз в месяц - и то не (в) каждый" - корректно?

Tags: стилистика, грамматика, лексическая-сочетаемость

Корректна ли конструкция ***"раз в месяц - и то не каждый"***? Или, как вариант: ***"раз в месяц - и то не в каждый"***?
Пунктуацию можете любую поставить, меня интересуют именно само сочетание выражения "раз в месяц", означающего частотность некоего действия, и "не каждого", что подразумевает некий календарный месяц. Все вместе должно означать примерно "(немного) реже, чем раз в месяц".

Контекст, если вдруг нужен: *"Я в том магазине бываю раз в месяц, и то не (в) каждый"*. Но не настаиваю, любой другой подходит и интересен.

(+)

Добавлю - с учетом уже имеющихся ответов.
***Ежедневно - но не каждый день***. - Все согласны, что это нонсенс? Так вот, нет ли в моей исходной фразе чего-то подобного?

Answer (score 4):

Вполне корректна,предлоги часто пропускаются при повторе, конструкции от этого только выигрывают в свете современной тенденции языка к экономии средств и упрощению. Всё понятно, никаких двойных прочтений нет.

"раз в месяц (какой?) - каждый, не каждый, осенний, весенний и  т.д. "

Comment: Дело не в предлоге, Людмила. А в самом сочетании "раз в месяц", и "не каждый" в одной фразе. Я не могу избавиться от ощущения внутренней противоречивости самого высказывания.

Comment: Если не в предлоге, то мне не нравится "и то", точнее будет "а то и не каждый".Или:  "Я в том магазине бываю раз в месяц, и даже не (в) каждый". "И то" относится скорее к сказуемому, например, в таком предложении: Я там бываю раз в месяц, и то больной...Или: Я там бываю раз в месяц, и то быстро ухожу.

Comment: *Я в том магазине бываю раз в месяц, и даже не (в) каждый"* -  А это вы считаете безупречным по смыслу? Понимаете, если Вы меня убедите, что здесь нет смысловой нестыковки, все остальное будет ловлей блох. Я еще раз попытался сформулировать, что получается.  *"Ежемесячно, но не каждый месяц"* - как-то так. Бывает такое?

Comment: Наверно, бывает, это же присоединение, мало ли какие нестыковки могут быть в присоединении, даже алогизмы встречаются (не только уточнения, но и опровержения ), но здесь алогизмов нет, всё воспринимается нормально

Comment: Людмила, спасибо, но нестыковки здесь не грамматические. Ежемесячно - это каждый месяц. А рядом - но не каждый. ***"Каждый месяц, но не каждый"*** - вот все, что я хочу понять с самого начала. Есть тут такой смысл, оксюморон это или нет? С остальным-то можно разобраться.

Comment: А я и говорю не о грамматических нестыковках, а о смысловых. В присоединительных и пояснительных конструкциях (это же разговорная речь) встречаются фразы с противоположным смыслом, это допустимо. Человек сказал, а потом подумал и поправил. В Вашей фразе не вижу противоречия, потому что " раз в месяц "- не обязательно каждый месяц, воспринимается и как "очень редко".  Получается смысл "Раз в месяц, а то и реже". "Каждый месяц, точнее, даже не каждый...".Понятно, что реже чем раз в месяц. И уж никак не оксюморон.

Comment: *"раз в месяц "- не обязательно каждый месяц,* - а, вот этого я и добивался. Я-то понимаю это именно как "обязательно" и "каждый". Во всяком случае допускаю такое понимание. Ладно, Вас понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что при таком упрощении возможна только предложная форма ("в каждый"), поскольку именно "освежающее" повторение предлога позволяет "разбить" единицу измерения периодичности 1/мес. и отнести "разы" из неё к любому отдельно взятому месяцу ("каждому"):

> раз в месяц, и то не в каждый
>
> (но не в каждый месяц случается по разу: бывает, что ни разу)

Тем не менее, поскольку при восприятии приходится домысливать слова и оценивать корректность такого упрощения, это стилистически хуже выражения с независимой второй частью, без предлога:

> раз в месяц, и то не каждый месяц (= не чаще, чем раз в месяц)

Comment: Вопрос не в предлоге. Согласен рассмотреть вариант с ним. С предлогом фраза не вызывает ощущения смыслового ляпа?

Comment: Вызывает, но при попытке разобраться (как толкуется у меня в скобках) это начинает выглядеть допустимым, в отличие от варианта без предлога: в нем не удаётся объединить два разнородных по смыслу выражения (периодичность в виде числа и следование с пропусками), имеющиеся в полном варианте.

Answer (score 2):

Грамматически верно, а почему нет?
Стилистика тут сильно завязана на понимании. я считаю, что раз в месяц - это оценка. Примерно с такой частотой. А и то не в каждый - это меньше. Вот и получается "Каждый месяц, но не каждый". Отсюда ощущение ошибки. Если все понимать по-другому, то, возможно, и ошибки не будет.

Comment: Ощущение ошибки или ошибка?

Comment: Ощущение. Был бы уверен, что ошибка, так бы и сказал.